# Iterate images with there corresponding id,with nested iterator

Tags: struts2, iterator

I want to iterate two iterator tags,where one contains imageString(BASE64) others contain 
images Id...and each image should have url link to the action class...
here is what i tried..

```
<s:iterator value="imgList" var="image" status="iteratorID">
<s:if test="#iteratorID.index==#iteratorIMAGE.index+1">
<s:url value="/LoadImage.action?image_id=%{image_Id}" var="GO" />
</s:if>
</s:iterator><s:a href="%{GO}">
img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<s:property/>" height="100" width="100"/>
</s:a></s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<
    s:iterator value="imgList" var="image" status="iteratorID">
    <
    s:if test="#iteratorID.index==#iteratorIMAGE.index">
    <
    s:url value="/LoadImage.action?image_id=%{image_Id}" var="GO" />
    <
    /s:if>
    <
    /s:iterator><s:a href="%{GO}">
    img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<s:property/>" height="100" width="100"/>
    <
    /s:a></s:iterator>
```

Comment: Edit your answer then ! ! ! !